# Span returning blank in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For my selenium script, I need to validate the below fields has the correct data(enter by user data) is showing or not. And I am trying to get the data by span, now span has more than one xpath so I am trying to getting it by index. Attaching the screenshot and code for reference.
[image]

```
public void verifyResellerInvolvedCompanyNameIs(String cName){
   String ActLegalName = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//span")).get(17).getText();
   Assert.assertEquals(ActLegalName,cName);
   log.info("Reseller Validation done");
}
```

Here is the html used for it.

```
<div class="reseller details"><div class="details-heading"><h3 class="heading1">Other Responsible Parties</h3><img src="/images/routing-attributes.svg"></div><div class="MuiGrid-root reseller-container MuiGrid-container"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12"><div class="MuiGrid-root title MuiGrid-container"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-2"><p class="reseller paragraph">Reseller Involved</p></div><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-10"><div class="value"><img src="/images/checked-new.svg"><span style="color: rgb(0, 121, 124);">Yes</span> </div></div></div></div><div class="info"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-spacing-xs-4"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-6"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-4"><p class="paragraph">Legal Name:</p></div><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-8"><p class="paragraph"><span>canonJapan</span></p></div></div></div><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-6"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-4"><p class="paragraph">Full Name:</p></div><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-8"><p class="paragraph"><span>canonJapan canonJapan</span></p></div></div></div></div><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-spacing-xs-4"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-6"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-4"><p class="paragraph">Phone number:</p></div><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-8"><p class="paragraph"><span>+14324232222</span></p></div></div></div><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-6"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2"><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-4"><p class="paragraph">Email address:</p></div><div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-8"><p class="paragraph"><span>sobhit.sharma@kaleyra.com</span></p></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Goal is to validate, its yes or no, if yes then details should be listed if and validate the fields with data and if no then ignore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or above, you can do that like this:

```
List<WebElement> spanList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//span"));
List<WebElement> yes = spanList.stream()
                 .filter(e->e.getText().equals("Yes"))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now you have a list of spans which text is "Yes" and you can continue your validation with data from this list

Answer (score 0):

Use the following solution;

```
// Give the label names in a String array
String[] labelArray = {"Legal Name:", "Full Name:", "Phone number:", "Email address:"};

// Then from the label element reach the value element using xpath
for (String label: labelArray) {
    WebElement valueElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),\'"+label+"\')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div/p/span"));

    System.out.println(valueElement.getText());
        
    if (!valueElement.getText().equals("")){
         // Do the necessary assertion here
    }    
}
```

printed output;

```
canonJapan
canonJapan canonJapan
+14324232222
sobhit.sharma@kaleyra.com
```